# Checking the sequence of conditions

Tags: pine-script

We need code that, given a certain signal, checks whether the conditions for the signal are met, regardless of time intervals.

For example, there is a certain order of conditions, if these conditions match, then a signal is displayed at the LIME mark.
Signal condition: RED YELLO LIME
A number of conditions:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13

- In this example, the signal should only be displayed on position 11, because the 9, 10 and 11 positions confirm the signal.

Done, thanks for the tip Bjorn Mistiaen 
Position results 01/08/2022 22:00 UTC, 01/09/2022 18:10 UTC and... etc

```
//  I recommend looking at the chart BTCUSDT 5M 
//  Position results 01/08/2022 22:00 UTC, 01/09/2022 18:10 UTC
//@version=5
indicator("Checking the sequence of conditions", overlay=true)

//  Variant with specific values        TOP              DOWN       //For example - there can be any other condition - true / false.
if01                        = close < 41600 and close > 40500       //Condition 1. Red.
if02                        = close < 41750 and close > 41650       //Condition 2. Yellow.
if03                        = close < 42100 and close > 42000       //Condition 3. Lime. 

//  To work with volume Close
plotSignal = false
var bufferR = 0             // Red signal buffer
var bufferY = 0             // Red signal buffer

//  Red signals
if if01
    bufferR:=1              
if if03 and bufferY != 1    // Red buffer clear condition
    bufferR:=0

//  Yellow signals
if if02 and bufferR == 1    // Yellow Buffer Accumulation Condition
    bufferY+=1
if if01                     // Yellow buffer clear condition
    bufferY:=0
    
//  Lime signals / all signal conditions are met
if if03 and bufferR == 1 and bufferY == 1
    plotSignal:=true
    
//  Clear all buffer
    bufferR:=0
    bufferY:=0

plotchar(plotSignal, char='', size = size.normal, location=location.top)

plotchar(if01, char='!', size = size.tiny, color=color.new(color.red, 0))
plotchar(if02, char='!', size = size.tiny, color=color.new(color.yellow, 0))
plotchar(if03, char='!', size = size.tiny, color=color.new(color.lime, 0))

plot(bufferR, color=color.new(color.red, 0))
plot(bufferY, color=color.new(color.yellow, 0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you intend.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Checking the sequence of conditions", overlay=true)

var int     offset          = input.int(30, 'Offset', 0)    // Check period

var bool    if01            = close > 40000                 // Condition 1 for example - there can be any other condition - true / false
var bool    if02            = close > 50000                 // Condition 2
var bool    if03            = close > 60000                 // Condition 3
var bool    n4              = false

var bool    if01_triggered  = false
var bool    if02_triggered  = false
var bool    if03_triggered  = false
var int     barCount        = 0


// once a signal is triggered, keep it triggered until reset
// next signal (for example if03) can only trigger if previous signal (for example if02) is triggered
if01_triggered := if01_triggered[1] or  if01
if02_triggered := if02_triggered[1] or (if02 and if01_triggered)
if03_triggered := if03_triggered[1] or (if03 and if02_triggered)

// first signal triggered?
if if01_triggered
    // start counting bars
    barCount += 1

// last signal triggered?
if if03_triggered
    // final signal (to plot) becomes true
    n4 := true

// last signal triggered, or barCount exceeds offset?
if if03_triggered or barCount >= offset
    // reset barCount 
    barCount := 0

    // reset triggers
    if01_triggered := false
    if02_triggered := false
    if03_triggered := false

    // reset final signal (to plot)
    n4 := false
    
plotchar(n4, char='', size = size.normal, location=location.top)
```

**Edit 1** in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70716007/checking-the-sequence-of-conditions/70716524?noredirect=1#comment125023268_70716524)

I see that I made a mistake in my previous code, because once `if03` is triggered, and sets `n4` to `true`, it's immediately reset again, so `n4` will never be `true`.

This should fix it.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Checking the sequence of conditions", overlay=true)

var int     offset          = input.int(30, 'Offset', 0)    // Check period

var bool    if01            = close > 40000                 // Condition 1 for example - there can be any other condition - true / false
var bool    if02            = close > 50000                 // Condition 2
var bool    if03            = close > 60000                 // Condition 3
var bool    n4              = false

var bool    if01_triggered  = false
var bool    if02_triggered  = false
var bool    if03_triggered  = false
var int     barCount        = 0

// last signal triggered, or barCount exceeds offset?
if if03_triggered[1] or barCount >= offset
    // reset barCount 
    barCount := 0

    // reset triggers
    if01_triggered := false
    if02_triggered := false
    if03_triggered := false

    // reset final signal (to plot)
    n4 := false

// once a signal is triggered, keep it triggered until reset
// next signal (for example if03) can only trigger if previous signal (for example if02) is triggered
if01_triggered := if01_triggered[1] or  if01
if02_triggered := if02_triggered[1] or (if02 and if01_triggered)
if03_triggered := if03_triggered[1] or (if03 and if02_triggered)

// first signal triggered?
if if01_triggered
    // start counting bars
    barCount += 1

// last signal triggered?
if if03_triggered
    // final signal (to plot) becomes true
    n4 := true

plotchar(n4, char='', size = size.normal, location=location.top)
```

Also, if you don't find a solution, please edit your question and post your entire code, because it's always easier to work on actual code than on pseudo-code. That way the community will be better able to help you.

**Edit 2**
I just noticed that you edited your question with a code example.
This should work, based on your example.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Checking the sequence of conditions", overlay=true)

var color   c_red           = color.new(color.red, 0)
var color   c_yellow        = color.new(color.yellow, 0)
var color   c_lime          = color.new(color.lime, 0)

var bool    plotSignal      = false

var bool    if01_triggered  = false
var bool    if02_triggered  = false
var bool    if03_triggered  = false

if01 = close < 41350 and close > 41240  //Condition 1. Red.
if02 = close < 41400 and close > 41295  //Condition 2. Yellow.
if03 = close < 41650 and close > 41540  //Condition 3. Lime. For example - there can be any other condition - true / false.

if plotSignal[1]
    if01_triggered := false
    if02_triggered := false
    if03_triggered := false

    plotSignal := false

if01_triggered := if01_triggered or  if01
if02_triggered := if02_triggered or (if02 and if01_triggered)
if03_triggered := if03_triggered or (if03 and if02_triggered)

if if03_triggered
    plotSignal := true


plotchar(if01,       'if01',       '!', location.belowbar, c_red,    size = size.tiny)
plotchar(if02,       'if02',       '!', location.belowbar, c_yellow, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(if03,       'if03',       '!', location.belowbar, c_lime,   size = size.tiny)

plotchar(plotSignal, 'plotSignal', '', location.top,               size = size.small)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your example, I liked your idea with validation. I'm trying to figure out how it works, because the conditions are not met :)

Comment: I see why conditions are not met. Added Edit 1 section to my answer.

Comment: I just noticed that you edited your question with a code example, so I added Edit 2 section to my answer.

Comment: I updated the code again, because. there were intersections of the results of the conditions on one bar.
Now I decided to test your code, but for some reason nothing is displayed on the chart. In any case, thank you very much for the tips, I'm very pleased with the result! :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been careful, I just had to add it to the chart. Everything is displayed. Thanks again for the code example. I looked at the results - in your code, not all conditions are met correctly, the signals slip, as a result, a false signal is given, until I quite understand why.